# Can UPDATE lead to deadlocks

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, locking, deadlock, database-deadlocks

Can running the same UPDATE query concurrently lead to a deadlock?

Assume there's a table with millions of records and we need to update several thousand records at one shot.

```
UPDATE TABLEX
SET Column1 = '1'
WHERE Column2 BETWEEN 1 AND 10000
```

I'm wondering if running this query concurrently would lead to a deadlock as each update query may acquire page/row U locks in a different order.

In other words, is the following a possible scenario. The scenario is that two concurrent sessions run the same query to update the same set of records.

1. Session 1: Acquires Update lock on row 1 (Column2 = 1)
2. Session 2: Acquires Update lock on row 2 (Column2 = 2)
3. Session 1: Tries to acquire Update lock on row 2 but it fails as it's already held by Session 2. (Column2 = 2)
4. Session 2: Tries to acquire Update lock on row 1 but it fails as it's already held by Session 1. (Column2 = 1)
5. Deadlock is detected.

Here, my assumption is that each query may scan rows in a different order which implies locks on rows will be taken in different orders.

Comment: A deadlock only occurs when 2 process try to acquire **2** locks in reverse order. This won't happen with a straight update, because they are obtaining the same locks in the same order. Why would you run the **same** update concurrently anyway? PS whats with the backticks - thats not valid SQL Server is it?

Comment: So, my question is that is there a guarantee that db engine scans rows in the same order for each concurrent query? If there's no guarantee, then a deadlock would be possible based on the scenario I mentioned.

Comment: Well, if your queries were identical probably? But why would you run 2 identical queries? From the start of your question it would seem you are updating *different* rows concurrently? But then later you imply the same rows - can you explain?

Comment: @DaleK It's a simplification. But it's not uncommon. For example, It's quite common that a web application serves concurrent requests and each request runs the same query.

Comment: Its probably an oversimplification for the question you have asked. The specifics have a big impact in this case. For example I can't imagine you accidentally concurrently updating 1000 rows from 2 different clients on your web app.

Comment: How does it affect how SQL server obtains locks on scanned rows?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228556/discussion-between-ehsan-mirsaeedi-and-dale-k).

Comment: Yes. Updates can lead to deadlocks. You need to be more specific about what you are trying to do.

Comment: @MitchWheat Can running the same UPDATE query concurrently lead to a deadlock? If yes, is it because locks on rows are taken in a different order?

Comment: @DaleK I noticed what you said in the chat. You are not quite correct. *If* (big if) the rows are accessed in a different order, then of course you can get a deadlock, either on a rowlock or a pagelock (assuming there is no tablelock). But with **identical queries**, on the same columns and same parameters, and **no** statistics update (or other query plan refresh), then you will not normally get a deadlock, only blocking as you say.

Comment: @EhsanMirsaeedi It would depend on the query plan, in turn depends on what indexes are in place and the statistics. If the query plans are different then you can get a deadlock.

Comment: Thanks @Charlieface for your answer. I'm trying to understand how having indexes can affect the order. Can we say having an index leads to a deterministic scan order?

Comment: No. We can say that *a particular query plan* accessing the index in a specific direction, woul dbe deterministic. The actual choosing of a query plan is very often not deterministic.

Comment: @Charlieface even if accessed in a different order what would the **2** resources be? The row is only one...

Comment: @DaleK Rowlocks are per row, if query 1 accessed 2 rows of the clustered index in allocation order and query 2 accessed them in key order for example, then you could have a deadlock between two rowlocks. Admittedly this is pretty unlikely to happen. Deadlocks are much more likely when you have an NCI which does not cover the query and causes out of order key lookups

Comment: @Charlieface yeah, but would that deadlock, or would one process just get blocked? Anyway as we've both said it comes back to the specific update, and table definition, it can't be answered in a generic fashion. And having 2 processes updating thousands of rows identically sounds like a design flaw regardless of deadlocks.

Comment: @DaleK It may deadlock, yes. But I agree with every other point you just made. I have a purely theoretical, contrived argument and it's very unlikely to happen.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with what others have said -- that running this particular query from two different sessions would not cause deadlocking, as there is no cross referencing involved.

So let's see what happens when we try...

I setup your TABLEX like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.TableX
(
    [id] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1)
        CONSTRAINT [PK_TableX] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    , [Column1] CHAR(1) NULL
    , [Column2] INT NULL
        CONSTRAINT [UQ_TableX_Column2] UNIQUE
) ;
WITH cte_Nums AS
(
    SELECT  1 AS [n]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  [n] + 1
    FROM    cte_Nums
    WHERE   [n] < 500000
)
INSERT
    INTO    dbo.TableX ( [Column1], [Column2] )
SELECT      'x', [n]
FROM        cte_Nums
OPTION      ( MAXRECURSION 0 ) ;
GO
```

Then I ran the same UPDATE query from 2 different sessions (spids 61 & 58), leaving the transaction hanging in order to see what locks are taken:

```sql
BEGIN TRAN ;

UPDATE  dbo.TableX
SET     [Column1] = '1'
WHERE   [Column2] BETWEEN 1 AND 10000 ;
```

Then, in a third session, I ran `sp_lock` to grab locking information:

```sql
EXEC sp_lock 61, 58 ;
```

And here are the results:

| spid | dbid | ObjId | IndId | Type | Resource | Mode | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 58 | 11 | 0 | 0 | DB |  | S | GRANT |
| 61 | 11 | 0 | 0 | DB |  | S | GRANT |
| 61 | 11 | 565577053 | 0 | TAB |  | X | GRANT |
| 58 | 11 | 565577053 | 0 | TAB |  | IX | WAIT |

So it appears, in this case at any rate, that SQL Server grants an exclusive (X) lock on the entire table to the first query (spid 61), thus preventing the second query (spid 58) from touching any rows until the first update is complete.

The answer to your question, given the example you've provided, is no. This same UPDATE query, running concurrently from different sessions, will not lead to a deadlock, because the lock to update is taken on the whole table, rather than individual rows.

Comment: Sorry this really isn't always correct. For example, if statistics change between the two queries being run (or any other recompilation), they could use different acces patterns. This particular example will probably use a key lookup from the unique index, but it could equally use a clustered index scan if there are a lot of estimated rows